# Could I somehow make my machine have bandwidth priority?

Tags: router, bandwidth

I have an old DLINK DIR-300 Router with my 1 PC Connected to it and everyone else is connected wirelessly... around 6-8 Devices.

Could I somehow make my machine/PC have bandwidth priority?
Could I make a some kind of switch between priority and normal modes?

I have read something about QoS, DMZ settings and I didnt understood what it exactly means and do.

Comment: Take a look over [here](http://www.dlink.com/nl/nl/support/faq/cameras-and-surveillance/mydlink/settings/router/how-do-i-configure-global-qos-on-my-dir-series-router) and [here](http://www.dlink.com/nl/nl/support/faq/cameras-and-surveillance/mydlink/settings/router/how-do-i-configure-the-qos-rules-on-my-dir-series-router).

Comment: @doenoe sadly my router doesnt have that option QoS Engine..